# Render alternate view in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, render

I have the following code in my controller

```
  def create
    @severity = Severity.new(params[:severity])
    if @severity.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created severity"
      render 'save'
    end
  end
```

I am trying to get the method to render another view file other than create.js.erb however the controller always renders the default rather than the save.js.erb.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def create
  @severity = Severity.new(params[:severity])
  if @severity.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created severity"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :template => "/path/to/save" }
    end
  end
end
```

or

```
def create
  @severity = Severity.new(params[:severity])
  if @severity.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created severity"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :file => "/path/to/save.js.erb" }
    end
  end
end
```

try this

```
def create
  @severity = Severity.new(params[:severity])
  if @severity.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created severity"
  end
  render :file => "/path/to/save.js.erb"
end
```

Comment: this did not work, I added the render template version of the code pointing to severities/save and it still rendered the default create.js.erb file. Do I need to include the full path?

Comment: how do you cal this action? through ajax?

Comment: Yes I have a form_for with the :remote => true attribute

Comment: Still no luck, despite which method I use to try and render another view it always defaults to rendering create.js.erb

Comment: and if you'll try this: `render :text => "Hello world!"` if it won't return `hello world` then your problem is not about you think