# Rails: Render a .js.erb from another controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

How can I render a `.js.erb` from a controller that doesn't belong to the view it is going to be rendered in?

**For example:** How can I render `create.js.erb` in my pages view, from a `post_controller`?

**post_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
        format.js #{I think I need something in here?}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367426/rendering-a-partial-from-a-controller-in-rails?rq=1

Comment: The problem I have is that the .js.erb file I am trying to render is in another view folder (the create method is in the post_controller and I am trying to render a .js.erb in the pages view from the post_controller). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems there are several ways to achieve this:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { :location => path_to_controller_method_url(argument) }
end
```

[How do you respond_to another js file in the controller using Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167596/how-do-you-respond-to-another-js-file-in-the-controller-using-ruby-on-rails)

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
       :template => "classrooms/create_differently.js.erb", 
       :layout => false
    }
end
```

[Render alternate view in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613747/render-alternate-view-in-ruby-on-rails)

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :file => "/path/to/save.js.erb" }
end
```

Comment: Concerning option 2, I believe you should have:

`format.js { render :template => "classrooms/create_differently.js.erb" }`