# Is it possible to specify what js.erb file I want to run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have the following code, Rails is setup to automatically look in the views folder and find `photos/feed.js.erb`. But what I want to do is to tell it to run `users/feed.js.erb` instead.

```
PhotosController
def feed
    @title = "Favorites" 
    @user_feed_items = current_user.favorites.order('created_at desc').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { 
               render 'users/feed' }
        format.js 
      end 
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails: Render a .js.erb from another controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055056/rails-render-a-js-erb-from-another-controller)

```
format.js { render :file => "/users/feed.js.erb"}
```

Comment: You might want to add layout: false to that:  format.js { render file: "/users/feed.js.erb", layout: false}

Answer (score 0):

`render` accepts the full path (relative to app/views) of the template to render. So, you can just enter `users/feed`

```
render "users/feed"
```

Rails knows that this view belongs to a different controller because of the embedded slash character in the string. If you want to be explicit, you can use the :template option.

```
render template: "users/feed"
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render